# Keep update a table created from another table

Tags: sql, cratedb

In CrateDB, after creating a table from data of another table, is it possible to keep the new table updated with the insertion of new lines from the original table?

Query to create the `new_table` from `enter code here`:

```
CREATE TABLE "schema"."new_table" AS
SELECT
state,
time,
time - LAG(time, -1, time) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC) AS duration
FROM "schema"."original_table"
ORDER BY timeDESC;
```

Query I run periodically to keep it the `new_table` updated, and which I would like to avoid using:

```
INSERT INTO "schema"."new_table"
SELECT
process,
time,
time- LAG(time, -1, time) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC) AS duration FROM "mtopcua_car"."original_table" newDataTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT time FROM "schema"."new_table" WHERE time = newDataTable.time);
```

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why a view would not be a possible solution for the above? I.e. `CREATE VIEW  xx AS stmt`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to CrateDB, maybe is the proper solution, checking out the documentation about ’VIEW’, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Just FYI, while we typically monitor stackoverflow for questions tagged with crate/cratedb, there also is http://community.crate.io

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! If you can place an answer in place of the comment, I will mark it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how expensive the query is, a view might just do the job:

```sql
CREATE VIEW "schema"."new_view" AS
SELECT
    state,
    time,
    time - LAG(time, -1, time) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC) AS duration
FROM "schema"."original_table"
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

CrateDB documentation: https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/5.1/general/ddl/views.html